Why does adding a std::list::iterator field to list elements significantly slow down pop_back in C++?
Problem Details
I'm working on a C++ project where I use a std::list<TestElement*> to store pointers to dynamically allocated objects. Each TestElement object has an additional field to store its position in the list using a std::list::iterator. The class looks like this:
class TestElement {
public:
    int value;
    std::list<TestElement*>::iterator listIterator; // Stores iterator to its position in the list
};

I populate both a std::list with 2 million TestElement objects. During initialization, I store the iterator of each object within its listIterator field.
The problem is that, when the listIterator field is present in TestElement, the pop_back() operation on the std::list becomes significantly slower. Specifically:

With the listIterator field: pop_back + delete takes 289.316 ms.
Without the listIterator field: The same operation takes only 0.0043 ms.

Since pop_back() should be a constant-time operation for std::list, this slowdown seems unexpected.
What did I do?
I created a std::list<TestElement*>, where each element in the list is a pointer to a TestElement.
I added an iterator field to each TestElement to store its position in the std::list.
I measured the time taken for the pop_back() operation both with and without the listIterator field in TestElement.
Here is the test program I used:
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <chrono>

class TestElement {
public:
    int value;
    std::list<TestElement*>::iterator listIterator;
};

int main() {
    const int numElements = 2000000;
    const int testIterations = 10;

    std::list<TestElement*> testList;

    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
        testList.push_front(new TestElement());
        testList.front()->listIterator = testList.begin();
    }

    double totalDuration = 0.0;

    for (int t = 0; t < testIterations; ++t) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        delete testList.back();
        testList.pop_back();

        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> duration = end - start;
        totalDuration += duration.count();
    }

    std::cout << "Average time for pop_back and delete operations: "
              << (totalDuration / testIterations) << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

I expected the performance of pop_back() and delete to be unaffected by the presence of the listIterator field. Since pop_back() is a constant-time operation for std::list, I didn't expect the addition of an iterator field in TestElement to cause any significant performance slowdown. However, adding the listIterator field resulted in pop_back() and delete taking 289.316 ms, compared to just 0.0043 ms without the field.

Have you enabled optimizations and built the Release config? Any measurements in Debug have no sense. If this is a debug build, then the iterator destructor and any other iterator operations check iterator validity.

In general the performance of std::list is worse than std::vector, modern processors don't like linked lists

Thank you for your insight! I tried building the project in Release configuration, and it resolved the performance issue I was experiencing.

This is not how you micro benchmark, all you're measuring is whether the compiler optimized everything out. Try quick-bench instead.

I measured with google benchmark the time to remove first 1000 elements (10 is too little for benchmarking) and typical results are 20ns vs 27ns, which is reasonable, because do destroy TestElement with listIterator member also std::list destructor has to be called.

"Each TestElement object has an additional field to store its position in the list" - It sounds like what you really want is an intrusive list. Check out the Boost.Intrusive library.

You are measuring it incorrectly. std::chrono by itself might not give you accurate results, and you are accumulating error with each iteration by totalDuration += duration.count();. Have in mind that on modern PC your single iteration takes a couple of ns.
To measure better, write a benchmark, e.g. using google benchmark library:
#include <list>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

class TestElement1 {
public:
  int value;
};

class TestElement2 {
public:
  int value;
  std::list<TestElement2 *>::iterator listIterator;
};

constexpr int numElements = 2000000;
constexpr int testIterations = 1000;

static void pop1(benchmark::State &state) {
  std::list<TestElement1 *> testList;
  for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
    testList.push_front(new TestElement1());
  }
  for (auto _ : state) {
    delete testList.back();
    testList.pop_back();
  }
}

BENCHMARK(pop1)->Iterations(testIterations);

static void pop2(benchmark::State &state) {
  std::list<TestElement2 *> testList;
  for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
    testList.push_front(new TestElement2());
    testList.front()->listIterator = testList.begin();
  }
  for (auto _ : state) {
    delete testList.back();
    testList.pop_back();
  }
}

BENCHMARK(pop2)->Iterations(testIterations);

Try to run it on your machine and compare results. If the results are still unstable, increase the number of iterations and/or elements. Always benchmark optimized release build.

I tried your test program with Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11 and an Intel Core I7-14700K.
Release build, x64 code:

With iterator:  0.00016 ms
Without iterator:  0.00015 ms

Release build, x86 code:

With iterator: 0.00028 ms
Without iterator: 0.00022 ms

Debug build, x64 code:

With iterator: 132.247 ms
Without iterator: 0.00085 ms

Debug build, x86 code:

With iterator: 37.3472 ms
Without iterator: 0.00092 ms

Your mileage will wary depending on the compiler & environment you use.
It matters whether you have optimizations enabled or not.
Also the debug builds & debug runtime libraries have extra correctness checks in the generated code
The list elements should get allocated from the heap, and a compiler/C++ runtime might have different strategies for allocating different sized objects. The visual C++ debug runtime library has also extra checks and accounting to enable detecting memory correctness errors.
Last, in my experience, in the case of visual C++, heap operations tend to be faster even for release builds if you run the code without the debugger attached.

that's because MSVC is using checked iterators in Debug build by default, which are fat (different ABI) and slow, you can turn them off: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/checked-iterators?view=msvc-170

@Gene But why would you want to (in a debug build). Checked iterators catch bugs.

@john -- I don't remember they ever caught a single bug, but from practical considerations, checked iterators are way too slow so you may not be able to comfortably debug, and another big problem, as I mentioned they are binary incompatible with regular iterators, so you can't mix debug and release code.
